# How can I see web surfing history a wireless router with Tomato firmware

Tags: wireless-router

Our old router had a page where I could see the details of recent internet traffic.  I can't find the same information in our new one (wrt54gl) by looking in the Tomato web UI or by SSH-ing into the device.  If it isn't there and there isn't a way to turn it on, what is a good strategy to monitor internet traffic in our home network?  Reasons for doing so are:

- Which sites are consuming the most bandwidth?
- Are children using Netflix or Minecraft when they are not allowed?
- Are any devices on our network contacting known bot networks or malware sites?

Comment: Ah, a reason to plug in my old WRT54GL running Tomato!